# Make an error pop-up box in visual basic (not VB.net)

Tags: asp-classic, popup

How do I make an error pop-up in Visual Basic?

UPDATE:
I tried making a pop-up in visual basic by saying

```
call MsgBox("This is a pop-up message", 0, "A Message")
```

I no longer get a compilation error, but now I get a run time error

> Permission denied: 'MsgBox'

Here's an outline of the code

```
<%
'other functions
Function parseString(aString)
    if startPos > 0 then
     'code
    Else
      call MsgBox("This is a pop-up message", 0, "A Message")
    End if
End Function
'other functions
%>
```

Comment: note: your code will works only in old version of InternetExplorer

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic's `MsgBox` function should do the trick.  Examples [here](http://www.vbtutor.net/lesson10.html):

```
MsgBox("This is a pop-up message", 0, "A Message")
```

Just replace the strings with your message text/title, and use the integer to control the buttons of the resulting pop-up.

Comment: I get the error message: Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

Comment: @jsmith: `MsgBox` should be a function, not a sub (my VB is very rusty, but I believe the language distinguishes between those very explicitly).  Can you update your question with code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Just remove the parentheses :) If you don't use the return value, VB considers that the function is a procedure/sub. So the call must be :
`MsgBox "This is a pop-up message", 0, "A Message"`

Comment: I don't get a compilation error anymore. Now, I'm getting a permission denied error.

Comment: @jsmith it does seem like a vbscript file (probably an ASP file? ) you cannot use msgbox with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    Dim i As Integer

```
i = MsgBox("Message", vbCritical, "title")
```

it will return 1 if error occurs .